# How to use xcom_push=True and auto_remove=True at the same time when using DockerOperator?

Tags: python, airflow

## Problem

When running `DockerOperator` with `xcom_push=True`, `xcom_all=True` and `auto_remove=True`, the task raises an error as if the container is deleted before reading its `STDOUT`.

## Example

Consider the following DAG as an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


# Default (but overridable) arguments for Operators instantiations
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Satan',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 11, 28),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=2),
}


# DAG definition


def createDockerOperatorTask(xcom_all, auto_remove, id_suffix):
    return DockerOperator(
        # Default args
        task_id="docker_operator" + id_suffix,
        image='centos:latest',
        container_name="container" + id_suffix,
        api_version='auto',
        command="echo 'FALSE';",
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        network_mode="bridge",
        xcom_push=True,
        xcom_all=xcom_all,
        auto_remove=auto_remove,
    )


# Use dag as python context so all tasks are "automagically" linked (in no specific order) to it
with DAG('docker_operator_xcom', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)) as dag:
    t1 = createDockerOperatorTask(xcom_all=True, auto_remove=True, id_suffix="_1")

    t2 = createDockerOperatorTask(xcom_all=True, auto_remove=False, id_suffix="_2")

    t3 = createDockerOperatorTask(xcom_all=False, auto_remove=True, id_suffix="_3")


    # Set tasks precedence
    dag >> t1
    dag >> t2
    dag >> t3
```

If we run it, the first task fails and the other 2 succeed. Nevertheless, the only one that runs "correctly" is `docker_container_3` because it sets the `xcom_value` correctly while `docker_container_2` doesn't. This gives me the feeling that it "tries" to read the `STDOUT` and when it can't, it doesn't fail (as it should, as `docker_container_1`).

### Run status per task

[image: dag run status]

### Log of task `dock_operator_1` with `xcom_push=True`, `xcom_all=True` and `auto_remove=True`

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/docker_operator_xcom/docker_operator_1/2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://5df603088df3:8793/log/docker_operator_xcom/docker_operator_1/2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00/1.log

[2019-12-04 20:24:24,959] {{taskinstance.py:630}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_1 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,984] {{taskinstance.py:630}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_1 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,984] {{taskinstance.py:841}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,984] {{taskinstance.py:842}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,985] {{taskinstance.py:843}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,998] {{taskinstance.py:862}} INFO - Executing <Task(DockerOperator): docker_operator_1> on 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,998] {{base_task_runner.py:133}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'docker_operator_xcom', 'docker_operator_1', '2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00', '--job_id', '72', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/qm_operators/exp_5_prueba.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmp4_eb_wcg']
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,987] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 [2019-12-04 20:24:25,986] {{settings.py:252}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=1037
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,006] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,006] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   """)
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,838] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 [2019-12-04 20:24:26,838] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,841] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 [2019-12-04 20:24:26,838] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/qm_operators/exp_5_prueba.py
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,982] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 [2019-12-04 20:24:26,982] {{cli.py:545}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_1 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [running]> on host 5df603088df3
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,001] {{docker_operator.py:201}} INFO - Starting docker container from image centos:latest
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,519] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Attachs:  []
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,575] {{taskinstance.py:1058}} ERROR - 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such container: 635f096a834e1fa20f4252287161f7a4765eed0f2aec706c1e5859e6c50dbdbe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.39/containers/635f096a834e1fa20f4252287161f7a4765eed0f2aec706c1e5859e6c50dbdbe/json

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py", line 264, in execute
    if self.xcom_all else str(line)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 855, in logs
    output = self._get_result(container, stream, res)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 451, in _get_result
    return self._get_result_tty(stream, res, self._check_is_tty(container))
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 447, in _check_is_tty
    cont = self.inspect_container(container)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 758, in inspect_container
    self._get(self._url("/containers/{0}/json", container)), True
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such container: 635f096a834e1fa20f4252287161f7a4765eed0f2aec706c1e5859e6c50dbdbe")
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,583] {{taskinstance.py:1089}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     response.raise_for_status()
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.39/containers/635f096a834e1fa20f4252287161f7a4765eed0f2aec706c1e5859e6c50dbdbe/json
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,639] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     args.func(args)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 551, in run
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 469, in _run
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     pool=args.pool,
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py", line 264, in execute
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     if self.xcom_all else str(line)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 855, in logs
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     output = self._get_result(container, stream, res)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,640] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 451, in _get_result
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     return self._get_result_tty(stream, res, self._check_is_tty(container))
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 447, in _check_is_tty
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     cont = self.inspect_container(container)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 758, in inspect_container
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     self._get(self._url("/containers/{0}/json", container)), True
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,641] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     self._raise_for_status(response)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,649] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,649] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,649] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,649] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1     raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,649] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 72: Subtask docker_operator_1 docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such container: 635f096a834e1fa20f4252287161f7a4765eed0f2aec706c1e5859e6c50dbdbe")
[2019-12-04 20:24:29,953] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-04 20:24:29,952] {{local_task_job.py:124}} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.989579 s
[2019-12-04 20:24:34,948] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-04 20:24:34,947] {{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

### Log of task `docker_operator_2` with `xcom_push=True`, `xcom_all=True` and `auto_remove=False`

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/docker_operator_xcom/docker_operator_2/2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://5df603088df3:8793/log/docker_operator_xcom/docker_operator_2/2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00/1.log

[2019-12-04 20:24:24,794] {{taskinstance.py:630}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_2 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,829] {{taskinstance.py:630}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_2 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,829] {{taskinstance.py:841}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,829] {{taskinstance.py:842}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,829] {{taskinstance.py:843}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,842] {{taskinstance.py:862}} INFO - Executing <Task(DockerOperator): docker_operator_2> on 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00
[2019-12-04 20:24:24,843] {{base_task_runner.py:133}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'docker_operator_xcom', 'docker_operator_2', '2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00', '--job_id', '71', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/qm_operators/exp_5_prueba.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpeq9uc4kw']
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,174] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 71: Subtask docker_operator_2 [2019-12-04 20:24:26,173] {{settings.py:252}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=1035
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,226] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 71: Subtask docker_operator_2 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,226] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 71: Subtask docker_operator_2   """)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,685] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 71: Subtask docker_operator_2 [2019-12-04 20:24:27,678] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,685] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 71: Subtask docker_operator_2 [2019-12-04 20:24:27,678] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/qm_operators/exp_5_prueba.py
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,973] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 71: Subtask docker_operator_2 [2019-12-04 20:24:27,971] {{cli.py:545}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_2 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [running]> on host 5df603088df3
[2019-12-04 20:24:28,017] {{docker_operator.py:201}} INFO - Starting docker container from image centos:latest
[2019-12-04 20:24:28,643] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Attachs:  []
[2019-12-04 20:24:29,783] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-04 20:24:29,782] {{local_task_job.py:124}} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.989846 s
[2019-12-04 20:24:34,780] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-04 20:24:34,779] {{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

### Log of task `docker_operator_3` with `xcom_push=True`, `xcom_all=False` and `auto_remove=True`

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/docker_operator_xcom/docker_operator_3/2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://5df603088df3:8793/log/docker_operator_xcom/docker_operator_3/2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00/1.log

[2019-12-04 20:24:24,992] {{taskinstance.py:630}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_3 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,031] {{taskinstance.py:630}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_3 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,032] {{taskinstance.py:841}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,032] {{taskinstance.py:842}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,032] {{taskinstance.py:843}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,054] {{taskinstance.py:862}} INFO - Executing <Task(DockerOperator): docker_operator_3> on 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00
[2019-12-04 20:24:25,055] {{base_task_runner.py:133}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'docker_operator_xcom', 'docker_operator_3', '2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00', '--job_id', '73', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/qm_operators/exp_5_prueba.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmp94dzo8w7']
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,219] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 73: Subtask docker_operator_3 [2019-12-04 20:24:26,219] {{settings.py:252}} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=1039
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,294] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 73: Subtask docker_operator_3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
[2019-12-04 20:24:26,294] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 73: Subtask docker_operator_3   """)
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,549] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 73: Subtask docker_operator_3 [2019-12-04 20:24:27,548] {{__init__.py:51}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,549] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 73: Subtask docker_operator_3 [2019-12-04 20:24:27,549] {{dagbag.py:92}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/qm_operators/exp_5_prueba.py
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,722] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Job 73: Subtask docker_operator_3 [2019-12-04 20:24:27,721] {{cli.py:545}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: docker_operator_xcom.docker_operator_3 2019-12-04T20:24:21.180209+00:00 [running]> on host 5df603088df3
[2019-12-04 20:24:27,754] {{docker_operator.py:201}} INFO - Starting docker container from image centos:latest
[2019-12-04 20:24:28,329] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Attachs:  []
[2019-12-04 20:24:29,979] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-04 20:24:29,979] {{local_task_job.py:124}} WARNING - Time since last heartbeat(0.01 s) < heartrate(5.0 s), sleeping for 4.989138 s
[2019-12-04 20:24:34,974] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2019-12-04 20:24:34,974] {{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

### XComs of `docker_operator_2`

[image: xcoms docker_operator 3]

### XComs of `docker_operator_3`

[image: xcoms docker_operator 3]

## Workaround

Even though setting `auto_remove=False`, as in `docker_container_2`, makes the task succeed and sets the XCom correctly, the container is never removed and future runs of the DAG will fail as the container of the old run will conflict with the container of the new runs.

A workaround for this is to add a task downstream that deletes the container, but it's not "clean".

Is there a way to run DockerOperator with `xcom_push=True` and `auto_remove=True` at the same time?

Comment: I presume this "Is there a way to run DockerOperator with xcom_push=True and auto_remove=False at the same time?" was meant to be "Is there a way to run DockerOperator with xcom_push=True and auto_remove=True at the same time?"

?

Comment: You're right, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [Docker operator source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py), I don't think so. It calls the Docker API clients `wait` [method](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.container.ContainerApiMixin.wait) and then calls the `logs` [method](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.container.ContainerApiMixin.logs) afterwards.

However, [the documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.container.ContainerApiMixin.create_host_config) for `auto_remove` states:

> enable auto-removal of the container on daemon side when the container’s process exits.

So as soon as the operator's call to `wait` completes, the container will be removed and you won't be able to retrieve the logs for it.

Comment: That was what I feared ... What method do you recommend of "cleaning by hand" the container created?

Comment: @Alechan personally I would create my own subclass of the DockerOperator, and override [_run_image](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py#L210) to `xcom_push` the created container id with a specific key, then later use a `PythonOperator` that `xcom_pull`s that id and then uses `DockerHook` to manually remove the container. 

Clunky I know, but probably the best you can do if you need both the last line of output, and to clean up the container.

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass `DockerOperator` and remove the container in `post_execute`. Like this:

```
class XComDockerOperator(DockerOperator):
    def post_execute(self, context, result=None):
        if self.cli is not None:
            self.log.info('Removing Docker container')
            self.cli.remove_container(self.container['Id'])
        super().post_execute(context, result)
```

Comment: Also, make sure `auto_remove` is `False`, or else the container will be long gone before this code runs