# Airflow docker commands comunicate via xCom

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have an Airflow docker container and two other containers (dc1 and dc2). And I'm trying to execute a command in dc1 (via DockerOperator) in task1 and its output to be used in a command to dc2 in task2.

I have a working solution but unfortunately, it is not robust :(

I'm reading the dc1 log and in the 99% it works

> command1.py

```py
# a simple version of the real script 
print({'date': '2020-05-03'})
```

> airflow/dags/dag1.py

```py
# a wrapper class 
class DOperator(DockerOperator):
    def __init__(self, task_id, command, dag, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            image='docker_image:latest',
            task_id=task_id,
            command=command,
            api_version='auto',
            auto_remove=True,
            docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
            network_mode='bridge',
            tty=True,
            xcom_push=True,
            dag=dag,
            *args,
            **kwargs
        )

    def execute(self, context):
        # get the last log line from docker stdout
        docker_log = super().execute(context)

        # push XComs from the json
        if docker_log:
            try:
                result = json.loads(docker_log)

                for key in result.keys():
                    context['ti'].xcom_push(key=key, value=result[key])
            except:
                pass

        return docker_log

# Dcocker container 1
task1 = DOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='task1',
    command='python comand1.py',  # its output is '2020-05-03'
)

# Dcocker container 2
task2 = DOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    command='python comand2.py --date={}'.format(
        "{{{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id='{}', task_ids='{}', key='{}') }}}}".format(
            dag.dag_id,
            task1.task_id,
            'date'
        )
)

task1 >> task2
```

> the dc1 log

```
[2020-08-31 06:50:38,868] {{docker_operator.py:242}} INFO - {"date": "2020-05-03"}
```

**But there is 1% when it doesn't**

In that case, the dc1 log contains one empty extra line and I can't extract the output correctly

> the dc1 log

```
[2020-08-31 06:50:38,868] {{docker_operator.py:242}} INFO - {"date": "2020-05-03"}
[2020-08-31 06:50:38,868] {{docker_operator.py:242}} INFO -
```

So my questions are:

- do you know how this issue can be fixed
- or do you know a better way to communicate between two docker operators?

Answer (score 6):

The following should work for what you are doing. My solution uses XCOM traffic to pass data between containers. It does require a task inbetween dockerized tasks so that the XCOM can be extracted. The following is my example dag I use to show others how to pass XCOM traffic in and out of a containerized Airflow Task. I know it works on Airflow `1.10.6`. I just upgraded to `1.10.12` and I am having some issues with the `XCOM_JSON` not being passed to the container. Hope this helps.. and if you have questions just ask and I'll try and elaborate.

## Example DAG using Docker

*example_docker_dag.py*

```py
import time
import logging
import datetime
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable, XCom
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import ast


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

args = {
        'start_date': days_ago(1),
        'ownder': 'mjcamp'

        }

dag = DAG(
        dag_id ='example-docker-dag',
        default_args=args,
        max_active_runs=6,
        schedule_interval='@daily'
        )

def make_xcom_traffic(**context):
    print("some task that does things..")
    time.sleep(2)
    data = dict(test="Pass some data to the next task or tasks.", number=545)
    Variable.set("Example-XCom", data)
    return data # conventional way of doing XCOM ... don't have to really return anything but for uniforimity sake


def read_xcom(**context):
    print("Read XCOM from DockerOperator.. and maybe do things..")
    time.sleep(1)
    # Grab xcom from previous task(dockerized task)..
    data = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids=context['task'].upstream_task_ids, key='return_value')
    # Airflow seems to be broken and will return all 'stdoout' as the XCOM traffic so we have to parse it or
    # write our code to only `print` the serialized thing we want.. in this case we are just printing a directionary.
    # if you do something like this and have string data in your return value.. either don't use
    # new lines for your stirngs or choose a different way to break things..

    xcom_data = data[0].split('\n')[-1]
    print("THIS IS WHAT I WANT:", xcom_data)
    xcom_data = ast.literal_eval(xcom_data)
    # Showing we have a python dictionary now...
    print("Int =>", xcom_data["Int"])
    print("Str =>", xcom_data["Str"])
    print("Float =>", xcom_data["Float"])


t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='make-xcom-traffic',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=make_xcom_traffic,
        dag=dag)

t2 = DockerOperator(
        environment={
            "Example-XCom" : Variable.get("Example-XCom"),
            },
        task_id="docker-text",
        image="example-docker-task",
        auto_remove=True,
        xcom_push=True,
        xcom_all=False, # <<<=== things are broken in Airflow and this doesn't do what you expect.. it does nothing
        docker_url='unix:///var/run/docker.sock',
        # docker_conn_id='containeryard',
        api_version='auto',
        dag=dag
        )

t3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='var-test',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=read_xcom,
        dag=dag
        )

t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

## The Containerized Task

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV EXAMPLE_XCOM=not-set

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY ./code.py /tmp/code.py

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python", "/tmp/code.py"]
```

*requirments.txt*

```
pandas==0.24.2
numpy==1.17.1
```

*code.py*

```py
import ast
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime
import json
import glob


xcom_json = os.getenv('XCOM_JSON')

print('Hello, from Airflow-Worker!')
print('Time on deck is...', datetime.now())
# Jst to show what things get passed in as environment variables
print('My ENV is >>', os.environ.keys())
# Data being passed in as XCom like variable
print("Received EXAMPLE XCOM TRAFFIC >>", os.getenv("Example-XCom"))
xcom_data = ast.literal_eval(os.getenv("Example-XCom"))

print("The Number =>", xcom_data["number"])
intvar = np.random.randint(0,100)
strvar = "test_string ===>>" + xcom_data["test"]
floatvar = np.random.rand() * xcom_data["number"]

# make a dictionary / json like object to return in `stdout`
result = dict(Int=intvar, Str=strvar, Float=floatvar)

# return the results as stdout for airflow
print(result)
```

## Airflow Variable

```
Key: Example-XCom
Value: {'test': 'Pass some data to the next task or tasks.', 'number': 545}
```

Comment: Is this working? I wrote a code as same as your code above. But I got error a KeyError: 'Variable Example-XCom does not exist'. Is the Variable Object could be accessed not only in each task but also in the dag code ?

Comment: You need to go create the `Example-XCom` variable in Airflow.. sorry about not being clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try add `xcom_all=True` when instantiating the Docker Operator. From the [airflow DockerOperator docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.3/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html#module-airflow.operators.docker_operator):

> xcom_push (bool) – Does the stdout will be pushed to the next step using XCom. The default is False.

> xcom_all (bool) – Push all the stdout or just the last line. The default is False (last line).

Setting `xcom_all` to True should push all the log lines to XCOM, which you can then parse in your downstream task to retrieve the information you want. This way you're not reliant on your data being at the end of the logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a solution. If I use `xcpm_all=True` it throws an exception "No such container ..." because I'm using `auto_remove=True` (destroy the container after the command finished"

Comment: take a look at this post, there are a few suggestions you can try alongside what I suggested above (I would subclass the operator, I've done something similar myself and it works well): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184551/how-to-use-xcom-push-true-and-auto-remove-true-at-the-same-time-when-using-docke#answer-61511481